using parent licence with a GPL v3 licence
I have a custom commercial licence I've made that prevent sharing my code and charging for it.This licence also mention that any third libraries keep their original licence intact. I want to use some code from a GPL v3 licence but the rest of it is commercial code of my own. So my question is, can I use my custom licence and use the GPL v3 only for the code I've copied (keeping the licence and source code visible on this part)?

Could you take a look at this Q&A and tell us whether it answers your question?  If not, what remains unanswered?

@MadHatter thank you for your answer, this answer my question.

OK, thank you for letting us know!
